# Published pod version is not up on the cocoapods.org server

Tags: cocoapods

After publishing the pod, the `cocoapods.org` server is still showing the previous version (`0.1`). Second attempt to publish returned `duplicate` error, but version is not found if pulled.

Is this just a delay, or were there some changes in the system? I can't pull `0.2` despite its published output.

```
  Congrats
  irishpod (0.2) successfully published
  January 17th, 16:23
  https://cocoapods.org/pods/irishpod
  Tell your friends!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turned out to be a delay, version № synced after 30 hours